# Prolog: Repeating Sequences

Tags: prolog

I want to make a simple program that repeatedly extends a list by another list, but give a result every step on the way.

I have something like this, it only runs once:

```
repeat(S, R, X) :- append(S,R,X).

:- repeat([y], [x], X).
X = [y,x].
```

Then I tried this, which runs forever:

```
repeat(S, R, X) :- append(S,R,X), repeat(S,R,X).
```

What ways can i make this program output something like:

```
:- repeat([y], [x], X).
X = [y,x];
X = [y,x,x];
X = [y,x,x,x];
x = [y,x,x,x,x];
....
```

I assume I need some kind of base case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you do need a base case. If you want to backtrack (press <kbd>;</kbd> for another answer), you at least have to have a choice. You need to be able to the last choice you made and choose differently.

A base case would be

```
% We append the tail to the head.
repeat(H, T, L) :- append(H, T, L).
```

A different choice would be

```
% We repeat H and T (the base case) and then append T to that.
repeat(H, T, L) :-
   repeat(H, T, L1),
   append(L1, T, L).
```

Answer (score 1):

> but give a result every step on the way.

As you know, Prolog can step forward *or* backward.

Then could be better to separate the functional request to extend a list by another, that's already covered by append/3, by the replication part. This last is better coded using difference lists, easily interfaced by phrase/3:

```
% service 'grammar'
enlist(L), L --> [] ; enlist(L).
```

that yields

```
?- phrase(enlist([1,2]), [], L).
L = [1, 2] ;
L = [1, 2, 1, 2] ;
...
```

then we can write

```
repeat(S, R, X) :-
    append(S, P, X),
    phrase(enlist(R), [], P).
```

and we obviously get

```
?- repeat([a,b],[1,2],L).
L = [a, b, 1, 2] ;
L = [a, b, 1, 2, 1, 2] ;
...
```

Comment: Using semicontext in that manner is a bit problematic. Semicontext should rather only used with a fixed number of elements like `nt, [a,b] --> ... .`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
repeat(S, R, X) :-
    S = X; append(S,R,X1), repeat(X1,R,X).
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to CapelliC's solution, using DCG, offered here only as a slight variation that doesn't use `append` and avoids redundant solutions for `R = []`.

```
rep(S, _) --> S.
rep(S, R) --> {R \= []}, rep(S, R), R.

repeat(S, R, X) :- phrase(rep(S, R), X).
```

This yields:

```
| ?- repeat([y], [x], L).

L = [y] ? ;

L = [y,x] ? ;

L = [y,x,x] ? ;
...
```

And:

```
| ?- repeat([a,b],[1,2],L).

L = [a,b] ? ;

L = [a,b,1,2] ? ;

L = [a,b,1,2,1,2] ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do it the simple way?

```
repeat(Xs,Ys,Zs) :- append(Xs,Ys,Zs) .
repeat(Xs,Ys,Zs) :- append(Xs,Ys,Ts) , repeat(Ts,Ys,Zs) .
```

Or

```
repeat(Xs,Ys,Zs) :-
  append(Xs,Ys,Ts) ,
  (
    Ts=Zs
  ;
    repeat(Ts,Ys,Zs)
  ) .
```

Comment: This is similar to joel76's solution, which is a little simpler. ;)